# Каким способом образовано слово "сквернословие"?

Tags: словообразование

Каким способом образовано слово "сквернословие"? ЕГЭ утверждает, что  суффиксальным. Почему? Объясните, пожалуйста!

Answer (score 3):

Сквернословие - от сквернословить с помощью суффикса -й (j): сквернослови/[j]/э, сквернослови/[j]/а, сквернослови/[j]/у.

Answer (score 0):

На мой взгляд, "сквернословие" образовано сложением корней вместе с присоединением суффикса -j-. 
Сравним со словами *баснословие, богословие, злословие, корнесловие, многословие, острословие, послесловие, празднословие, предисловие, пустословие, славословие, срамословие, суесловие.* Только часть из них имеют соответствующие глаголы, что говорит о том, что глаголы являются производными от существительных. В пользу этой точки зрения можем рассмотреть суффиксы, используемые в девербативах (отглагольных существительных), близкий к -j- только -иj- (доверять - довер[иj]е)

[Источник](http://www.dialog-21.ru/digests/dialog2009/materials/html/57.htm)

"Сквернословие" не имеет никакого отношения к слову *square*.

Слово "сквернословие", по Фасмеру, происходит от праславянского *skvьrnъ, от которого произошли: древнерусское сквьрна «мерзость, нечисть», сквьрнъ «нечистый», старославянское сквръна (др.-греч. κηλίς, βόρβορος), укр. скверний, белор. скверня «нечистоты, грязь», словенск. skvr͂na, skrûnа «скверна», чешск. skvrnа «пятно, порок», словацк. skvrnа — то же. Праслав. *skvьrna, *skvьrnъ. Сближали ввиду значение со словом скаред, греч. σκῶρ, σκατός «навоз, отброс» и т. д. Затруднительно из-за -v-. Также считают это слово родственным лат. squarrōsus «покрытый струпьями, гадкий, нечистый». По мнению Махека, имеет смысл говорить о дальнейшем родстве с сербохорв. ква́рити «портить».

Answer (score -1):

По английски слово **ПЛОЩАДЬ**(городская) выглядит как  **SQUARE** , а звучит типа , как *СКВЭА*(*Р*) или *СКВЕР* . Например , the Trafalgar Square , - Трафальгарская площадь в Лондоне . Я не могу сказать точно , но вполне возможно , что и в латинском  и в европейских языках тоже есть (или были) обозначения городской площади со схожим звучанием . При этом ,  надо иметь в виду , что во *время оно* городская площадь являлась именно тем местом , где располагался рынок , трактиры или шинки , шла всевозможная торговля , кучковались пьяницы ,   уголовники , жулики , бродяги , проститутки и прочие люмпены . Разумеется , что и лексикон такой *публики* не вписывался в общепринятые нормы приличия . Вам нигде не встречалось словосочетание "**площадная брань**" ? Мне встречалось . Поэтому прилагательное **СКВЕРНЫЙ** , в смысле "**нехороший**" , по сути связано , как раз , со звуковым копированием слова **ПЛОЩАДЬ** с английского (или ещё какого-то) языка , -  произносимом как **СКВЕР** . То есть **СКВЕРНОСЛОВИЕ** это грубая , некультурная речь , - на подобие той , которая обыденно слышится **на городской площади** . В России слово **СКВЕРНОСЛОВИЕ** было в употреблении уже , как минимум , в 1-й половине 18-го века , - в стихотворной сатире Антиоха Кантемира , обличающей беспутство монахов , читаем : " *А иные буи **сквернословят** зело*..." .